# getLastKnownLocation always returns null in Android 10, after code was working fine in Android 9

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-uiautomator, android-9.0-pie

This code worked fine in Android API Level 29 (Android 9 / Pie) but when loaded into Android API Level 30 (Android 10) it no longer works. getLastKnownLocation() returns null every time for all providers. Even if I create a mock provider and set a location.

```
    public static Location getDeviceLocation(Context context)
    {
        // Request permission for location access
        PermissionRequester requester = new PermissionRequester();
        requester.addPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        requester.requestPermissions();

        // Get first device location found from providers
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Location deviceLocation = null;
        List<String> providers = manager.getAllProviders();
        for (String provider : providers)
        {
            deviceLocation = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (deviceLocation != null)
            {
                return deviceLocation;
            }
        }
        return deviceLocation;
    }
```

The [getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) method does not appear to have been deprecated.

This is being run in Cucumber step definition code (Android Test code for GUI tests using Gherkin and Cucumber) on an Android 10 emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`permission caused the above code to work again as is.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background